# JMS deliver message at later time

Tags: jboss, jms, hornetq

I am trying to deliver a JMS message after some time passes, my initial idea was to use expiry queue and to put the messages in a queue that doesn't have any consumers. So I have 3 default queues:

- **WaitQueue** - (expiry queue for this one is set to SendQueue)
- **SendQueue** - this one has consumers that process the messages(by default this one has expiryQueue as its timeout queue)
- **ExpiryQueue** - default jboss queue for all messages that really expired(not intentionally)

In insert a message into the WaitQueue with my intended delay as TimeToLive, after the time expires I expect to see the messages in SendQueue(and the consumers to process them), however it stays empty and the messages directly go to ExpiryQueue, any ideas what is wrong?

The statistics for SendQueue shows that "Received messages" increase, but current messages stays at 0, so they arrive but get forwarded immediately to the last ExpiryQueue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using expiry queue approach which is more resource intensive; you could consider using delivery delay at the Message level.

In case of HornetQ, you can set the property _HQ_SCHED_DELIVERY.
https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.3.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html/scheduled-messages.html

```
   TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("This is a scheduled message message which will be delivered in 5 sec.");
   message.setLongProperty("_HQ_SCHED_DELIVERY", System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000);
   producer.send(message);
```

Since JMS2.0 (JavaEE7) this property can also be set on MessageProducer. See https://github.com/jboss/jboss-jms-api_spec/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/jms/MessageProducer.java#L285